# Svg rect round looks different depend on its position

Tags: html, css, svg

[image]

I set rx="3" ry="5" to all rects, but looks different depend on its position at zoom 100% why is it? any Ideas?

top:

```
<rect x="217.5" y="-8" style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" 
width="45px" height="27px" rx="3" ry="5">
</rect>
```

```
<rect x="167.5" y="-8" viewBox="0 0 100 100" rx="3" ry="5" 
style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" width="45px" height="27px">
</rect>
```

right:

```
<rect rx="3" ry="5" x="356" y="73" style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" 
width="45px" height="27px" viewBox="0 0 100 100"></rect>
```

Comment: Do you have some css rule like `shape-rendering: crispEdges`? If so, remove it.

Comment: @Kaiido Nope I don't have any.

Comment: Really? Sounds weird you don't have any antialiasing... Can you try to make a [MCVE]?

Comment: From what browser/renderer is the screenshot? Did you try any other browsers/renderers?

Comment: FWIW viewBox does nothing on a rect element.

Comment: The problem was ```shape-rendering: crispEdges``` which @Kaiido said.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using `<foreignObject>`

```html
<foreignObject x="356" y="73" width="50px" height="40px">
    <div style="background-color:white; width:45px; height:27px; border-radius:4px; border:1px solid black;"></div>
</foreignObject>
```